# How to subscribe to change of route parameters in Angular?

Tags: angular

If I change the route parameters, nothing gets logged in the console.
The id parameter defined.

Does anyone know why this is not working that way?

```
export abstract class GenericLeftPanelComponent<T extends ItemIdName>
  implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  data: T[] = [];
  protected getSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  protected mainSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  protected refreshSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  protected startSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  protected constructor(
    protected genericService: GenericService<T>,
    protected router: Router,
    protected route: ActivatedRoute,
    @Optional() draggable: boolean
  ) {
    this.actionButtons = actionButtons;
    this.tableColumnDefinition = tableColumnDefinition;
    this.draggable = draggable;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.get();
    this.refresh();

    this.startSubscription.add(
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('id')) {
          console.log("view -", this.route.snapshot.params.id);
        }
      })
    );

...
```

Comment: How you change your parameter ?

Comment: Maybe `this.route.queryParams` is working?

Comment: My aim: On the left side I have a list of elements and when clicking on an element, a more detailed view of this element appears. The detailed section gets an id through the route. I want to highlight the selected element in the list, even if I change the id in the url field. Is there maybe another way to deal with this?

Comment: it's a params (:id) or queryParams (?id) ?

Comment: (:id) ```http://localhost:4200/#/settings/user-management/roles-and-permissions/7784a1a2-9499-4d5b-9781-e0c5c2b643b6```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are a little bit tricky and it depends on [RouterResueStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). If the route isn't reused you will never see changes because the component is recreated each time. It works that way by default. Another question of how you change your parameters? If you change query string parameters in the browser address bar and press enters you reload the whole application.

You can use router events if you need to track navigations and parameters are available there also.